# Symfony2/Assectic: 500 error when combinding LESS/CSS

Tags: symfony, assetic

When I add a second file to my other file it seems to cause a 500 error on the first one.

```
    {% stylesheets
        '@MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.less'
        '@MyTestBundleBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css'

    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Here is my assetic(it uses controller in dev):

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/lib64/node_modules]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```

If i remove the main.css it works fine.  If I move main.css to a different stylesheets block it also works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my less in node was the issue. Switching this to the latest in github (1.3.1) fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forget about filter attribute.

```
{% stylesheets '@MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.less' '@MyTestBundleBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css' filter='less,?yui_css'%}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Update.

I saw the `apply_to: "\.less$"` just now.

Split this block to 2 stylesheets

```
{% stylesheets '@...less' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url}}" ... />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% stylesheets '@...css' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url}}" ... />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: That'd be producing two different includes.  According to http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/assetic/apply_to_option.html#cookbook-assetic-apply-to you should be able to specify different types in a single block.

Comment: Yeah but here you need to chain the `assets dump` like this: less -> css next css merge with other css's.

Comment: Ended up being the less version on my node was the issue.  Updated to latest in git and its all working with combining them.